# Python - Multithreading is running sequentially

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I'm failing to see why is this running like sequentially process.

```
from queue import Queue, Empty
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import threading
import time
import random

pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3)
to_crawl = Queue()

#Import urls
for i in range(100):
    to_crawl.put(str(i))

def scraping(random_sleep):
    time.sleep(random_sleep)
    return

def post_scrape(url):
    print('URL %s finished' % url)

def my_crawler():
    while True:
        try:
            target_url = to_crawl.get()
            random_sleep = random.randint(1, 5)
            print("Current URL: %s, sleep: %s" % (format(target_url), random_sleep))
            executor = pool.submit(scraping(random_sleep))
            executor.add_done_callback(post_scrape(target_url))
        except Empty:
            return
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            continue

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_crawler()
```

Expected output:

```
Current URL: 0, sleep: 5
Current URL: 1, sleep: 1
Current URL: 2, sleep: 2
URL 1 finished
URL 2 finished
URL 0 finished
```

Real output:

```
Current URL: 0, sleep: 5
URL 0 finished
Current URL: 1, sleep: 1
URL 1 finished
Current URL: 2, sleep: 2
URL 2 finished
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the way you are calling `pool.submit`:

```
pool.submit(scraping(random_sleep))
```

This says submit the *result* of `scraping(random_sleep)` to the pool; actually, I'm surprised it doesn't cause an error. What you want to do is to submit the `scraping` function with the argument `random_sleep`, which is achieved with this:

```
pool.submit(scraping, random_sleep)
```

Similarly, the next line should be:

```
executor.add_done_callback(post_scrape)
```

And the callback should be declared as:

```
def post_scrape(executor):
```

Where `executor` will be the Future itself, the `executor` from the other code. Note there is no easy way to attach a user argument to this callback, so you can instead do something like this and drop the `add_done_callback`:

```
def scraping(random_sleep, url):
    time.sleep(random_sleep)
    print('URL %s finished' % url)
    return

#...

pool.submit(scraping, random_sleep, target_url)
```